# Join parent objects in a collection with their children

Tags: python, parent, collections

The thing is that I have a collection with multiple parent objects and I need to join these parents with their children. I have tried to iterate over each object in the collection with a For Loop, but I cannot get the result that I am looking for.

[image]

Here I attach an image to explain my point more clearly. I am iterating over the 'Openings' collection, and I want to join every single door and window with its own children.

I have tried many things, but I am new to Python and I cannot find a way.

My code so far is this:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.collections['Openings'].all_objects:
    parent_obj = bpy.context.active_object
    parent_obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.select_grouped(type='CHILDREN_RECURSIVE')
    bpy.ops.object.join()
```

I am pretty sure this code is wrong, but the others options I have tried do not work either.

I am using Blender 3.1 version.

I hope someone could help me with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a parented hierachy from the 3d viewport using the right click menu?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266193/how-to-select-a-parented-hierachy-from-the-3d-viewport-using-the-right-click-men)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. I need to join by scripting all parent objects in the mentioned collection with their own children, so that instead of having an object called 'Door' with a set of children (door panel, handle, etc.), I can get a single joined object with no hierarchy. And I need to do this with all the parent objects in the collection.