# Batch / string commands together. (cursor to selected, then set orgin to 3D cursor)

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut, keymap

Is there a way to batch / string commands together. The commands I want to execute right after each other is (**Cursor to selected**, then **set origin to 3D cursor**)

I would like to just select the faces of an object in edit mode.

Then:

1. The cursor gets moved to the selected (In edit mode)
2. The objects origin gets set to the cursor. (In object mode)

Example:
[image: ani1]

Ideally I would assign a shortcut to this or an icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Make custom operator

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Addon",
    "author": "X Y",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "my operator",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

class MY_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.my_operator"
    bl_label = "some label"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        if not context.object:
            print("object not find")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if context.object.type != 'MESH':
            print("MESH Only")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        obj = context.object
        if obj.mode == 'OBJECT':
            bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
        elif obj.mode == 'EDIT':
            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_active()
        else:
            print("OBJECT and EDIT mode Only")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OP)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

#### Install and Assign shortcut

[How to duplicate parented objects as one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263081/how-to-duplicate-parented-objects-as-one-object/263096#263096)

#### Extra

```
import bpy

class MY_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.my_operator"
    bl_label = "some label"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        if not context.object:
            print("object not find")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if context.object.type != 'MESH':
            print("MESH Only")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        obj = context.object
        if obj.mode == 'OBJECT':
            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
            bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
        elif obj.mode == 'EDIT':
            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        else:
            print("OBJECT and EDIT mode Only")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OP)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: active object only, Not support multi object for this script.

Comment: Thanks for the code when I ran it with F3 nothing happened.  I changed  `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_active()`  to `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()` and the cursor moved but the origin didn't move until I went into Object mode and ran it again.  Is there away to have this done all at once without running it twice (once in edit mode and once in object mode)? I'm using Blender 3.2.1

Comment: @RickT you're right. it works on the default cube, but doesn't work when i select an edge loop like in your scenario. but changing to `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()` works for me.