# How do I turn the Shade smooth/ Auto smooth functions into one Addon/Shortcut/Tool or whatever?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

Instead of clicking shade smooth, then auto smooth separately, I want to turn this into a single operation via python. I want this to work on all meshes I add in. How would I do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Info editor to find out python commands which you run through the UI. Switch to the Scripting workspace, and do right click > shade smooth ....

Here's the output

```py
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = True
bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle = 0.523598 # in radians (~ 30 deg)
```

[image: blender info editor output]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/info_editor.html

Comment: Ah okay, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### shade smooth and auto smooth for selected objects

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Addon",
    "author": "X Y",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "my operator",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

class MY_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.my_operator"
    bl_label = "some label"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.object:
            if context.object.mode != 'OBJECT':
                self.report({'WARNING'}, "Object mode only!")
                return {'CANCELLED'}

        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                data = obj.data
                data.polygons.foreach_set('use_smooth',  [True] * len(data.polygons))
                data.use_auto_smooth = True

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OP)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

#### Install and Assign shortcut

[How to duplicate parented objects as one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263081/how-to-duplicate-parented-objects-as-one-object/263096#263096)

Answer (score -1):

I notices potential for a few improvements in @X Y's script.

````
bl_info = {
    "name": "Set Shade Auto Smooth",
    "author": "X Y",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "description": "Set Shade Auto Smooth with one Click",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_shade_auto_smooth(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.shade_auto_smooth"
    bl_label = "Shade Auto Smooth"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    # put checking for object type and correct context 
    # in the poll method rather than execute.
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None and context.object.type in {"MESH", "CURVE"}

    def execute(self, context):
        # allows for use in edit mode and object mode alike.
        in_edit = 'EDIT' in context.mode
        if in_edit:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
        # using one operator call to act on all selected objects 
        # rather than looping over every polygon
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
        for obj in context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type == "MESH":
                obj.data.use_auto_smooth = True
        if in_edit:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")   
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_shade_auto_smooth)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_shade_auto_smooth)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````